# NumberFormatException at MatrixCursor column for searching in maps from database

Tags: android, search, matrixcursor

I'm using searching in my map search from database content using `MatrixCursor`. I have a  `NumberFormatException` in `Android SDK` version `2.2`. In my declaration I did:

```
private static final String[] COLUMNS = {

   _ID, // must include this column
   SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
   SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA };
```

and I also created the object for `MatrixCursor` that has:

```
MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
cursor.addRow(columnValuesOfQuery(query, s));
```

Here is the exception I'm getting:

```
10-22 23:11:33.734: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(456): error changing cursor and caching columns
10-22 23:11:33.734: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(456): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
10-22 23:11:33.734: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(456):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:347)
10-22 23:11:33.734: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(456):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:320)
10-22 23:11:33.734: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(456):     at android.database.MatrixCursor.getLong(MatrixCursor.java:255)
10-22 23:11:33.734: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(456):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:127)
10-22 23:11:33.734: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(456):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:156)
```

Why I'm getting this exception and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sounds similar to the exception retrived when using geocoder on the emulator in SDK 8.
my guess its another emulator bug related to the geocoder clas try this on a real device, or lower the SDK version on the emulator - Should do the trick.

Comment: When i use SDK 8 even in device and on emulator at that time only i'm getting this problem if i use less than 8 even in real time device i'm not getting like this problem,it is working good,please help me what can i do further.how can i fix this problem,help me.it's urgent.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said it is a emultor bug, It should work fine on a real device. For testing purposes on PC you could use lower SDK version. A bit of a pain in the A** but nothing to do about it.

Comment: I checked it on real time device sdk 8 still it'd getting same problem.

Comment: Hmm then possibly a bug in 2.2? I hope not sorry I had a similar problem but resolved it as a 2.2 emulator bug. And i have not tested on a 2.2 device yet so I hope it realy is an emulator bug. Maybe consider a different way to do what your are trying to do? possibly threw google API for geocoding on the web?

Comment: what version of map api you used..i'm using map 1.6

Comment: I am using 1.6 as well. however as I said haven't tested it on a real device. Possibly you could try a new API and see if that helps, But since it only stops working in 2.2 I would figure its more likely to be a 2.2 bug. One thing that should work for sure is using The 2.2 API for maps.